# Ajax success and error callbacks never get fired

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have searched high and low for an answer on SO but nothing worked. I'm trying to upload an image using ajax to the server and once the image has been uploaded, the server should return the path to the image, which is then displayed on the screen. The upload works fine but since the success (and not even error) callbacks are never fired, I can't display the uploaded image to the user (because I expect to get the results in the success callback) .

JSP

```
<form id="uploadData" action="UploadPhoto" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input   type="file" onchange="fileChanged('postImg')" name="postImg"    id="postImg" ><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload image" > 
</form>
```

Ajax

```
$(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#uploadData').ajaxForm(
                  {

                    success: function(data,status,xhr) {
                    alert("...success uploading image..."+status);
                        var dataMessage = data.split('|');
                        var isError = dataMessage[0] == "true" ? true : false;
                        var errorMessage = dataMessage[1];
                        var imageUrl = dataMessage[2];
                        //this should display the image
                            $("#postContent").htmlarea("image", "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/"+imageUrl);                 
                    },
                    error: function(errorMsg){
                         alert("...error uploading image..."+errorMsg);

                    },

                }
            );  
            });
```

});

Servlet

```
    Map<String,String> multipartItems = null;
    if((multipartItems=processMultiformatData(request))==null)
        return;

    String userImg = multipartItems.get("postImg");
    //response.setContentType("text/html");//tried this one too
    response.setContentType("text/plain");

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.getWriter().write(userImg);
```

The response in Chrome after the ajax call

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/SomeSite/UploadPhoto
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Response Headers
view source
Content-Length:12
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Sun, 24 Jan 2016 12:46:56 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headers
view source 
 Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,
application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2997
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----       WebKitFormBoundaryBLLyr0fgnS47WfqA
Cookie:JSESSIONID=03BC5363F392EB58FB043B87B5289733
Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryBLLyr0fgnS47WfqA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="postImg"; filename="4-128[1].png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

I do get the path in the response but since the success callback is never called, I can't display it on the screen (as part of the img tag).

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Of course, since I know the name of the image I'm sending and the server path is always the same (path+image) I can use this information to display the image if everything else fails.

Comment: That last snippet is not the response. It's the request.

Comment: True, although the response header is also present. The response content is just 4-128[1].png.:)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No, but  I can still get what I want for my simple use case (because I already know which file I'm uploading so I don't really depend on the server returning that).